# MagentoCE 1.9 shows product count although it shouldn't

Tags: magento, attributes

I use a custom attribute which is shown as `layered navigation` **(type=dropdown, use in filter navigation BUT without product count)**.
Everything is like it should be, but the frontend SHOWS the product count next to the filterable attribute. Anchor is on in Display Settings (Category).
I wonder if I forgot to set something or if my settings are overwritten...

```
Magento_AT version 1.9.0.1v1
(special language version based on MagentoCE 1.9.0.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are options `Filterable (with results)`, it means show this filter if there are some associated products in the listing. `Filterable (no results)`, it means show this filter always.

To hide product count try to modify template

`app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\layer\filter.phtml`

(copy it to your custom theme first)

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "show filter" and "show filter always". In my understanding (coming from MagentoGO) Filterable (no results) means show list the products associated with the chosen attribute but do not show how many products are associated with this product. Filterable (with results) means showing the product count next to the attribute in parentheses (dependent of course of other already selected filterable attributes).

Comment: "Filterable (with results) means showing the product count next to the attribute", no, in magento CE it works differently.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to hide the product count without modifying the template directly.
In `Configuration/Catalog/Filter Navigation` one can unselect show product count.